# RewriteRule htaccess doesn't works for long parameter

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm actually using this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([A-Za-z0-9%])/?$ index.php?get1=$1&get2=$2 [NC,L]
```

In order to convert this hypothetical url:

`.com/index.php?get1=portfolio&get2=jY1eF7FGR7k0zFYfdioRJOzzWJpkYXeTbmqUtamRV5U%3D`

in this one:

`.com/portfolio/jY1eF7FGR7k0zFYfdioRJOzzWJpkYXeTbmqUtamRV5U%3D`

(the get2 parameter is crypted and url encoded)
The problem is that when I insert this long parameter in get2, it give me a 404 not found page when I try to visit the desidered url, but if I try to insert random words (without special character or number) it works and give me the page. Anyone that know the reason?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below,

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\%]+)/?$ index.php?get1=$1&get2=$2 [NC,L,B]
```